# Why this finite difference method is stable for $r\leq1/2$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, numerical-methods, heat-equation, finite-differences, stability-in-odes

I was recently looking at [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference_method#Explicit_method) Wikipedia page, and specifically the section *explicit method for the heat equation*. To summarise, it says we can use the numerical scheme below.

> We have the differential equation $$U_t=U_{xx}$$
>   We want to numerically approximate the points at $(x_j,t_n)$ by $u_j^n$. By expressing the derivatives as $$U_t\approx\frac{u_j^{n+1}-u_j^n}{k}\text{ and }U_{xx}\approx\frac{u_{j+1}^n-2u_j^n+u_{j-1}^n}{h^2},$$ we can rearrange to get
>   $$u_j^{n+1}=(1-2r)u_j^n+r u_{j-1}^n+r u_{j+1}^n$$ where $r=k/h^2$

What I don't understand is why this is stable for $r\leq 1/2$ and why it would be unstable if $r>1/2$ - what causes this instability? Is it something to do with the $1-2r$ term, which we need to keep $\leq0$? If so, why?

Comment: You may want to look at [Von Neumann stability analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_stability_analysis).

Comment: @Eff I just read that page, and it says: _For linear differential equations with periodic boundary condition, the spatial variation of error may be expanded in a finite Fourier series_ $$\epsilon(x)=\sum_{m=1}^M A_m(t) e^{ik_mx}.$$ I can follow all the method after this, but why is this Fourier series justified?

Comment: The expansion is a complete set and so functions can be written as a linear combination of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Eff pointed out, Von Neumann analysis is the way to go. Suppose $u_j^n = z^n e^{i j \xi}$. Plugging this into the equation
$$ z = (1-2r) + r( e^{-i \xi} + e^{i \xi}) = (1-2r) + 2r \cos \xi. $$
The stability is only if $|z| < 1$ which implies
$$ -1 < r (\cos \xi - 1) < 0. $$
Note here, that $\cos \xi - 1 \le 0$ and so
$$ \frac{1}{1 - \cos \xi} > r > 0. $$
Finally, we want stability for all $\xi$ and so we take the minimum for the LHS which gives
$$ \frac{1}{2} > r > 0. $$

Comment: You used $e^{ij\xi}$ terms, whereas the Wikipedia page used $e^{\frac{i\pi j\xi}{L}}$ - I think I am missing some understanding as to why either of these can be used?

Comment: Also, this answer doesn't say anything about the case $r=1/2$, which is stable

Comment: Technically it is better practice to use the form from wiki. I was just showing the process. The result should be the same. You can also see this by noting that changing  $\xi \to c \xi$ gives the same result. Additionally, stability is actually given if $|z| \le 1$. Would you like me to edit or do you understand enough to take care of it?

Comment: Ahh, yes I can understand this (no need to edit), thanks very much for your help. :)