# What is "theoretical order of accuracy"?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, numerical-methods, finite-differences

I was studying a numerical solution to the heat equation, specifically [this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference_method#Explicit_method).  I will summarise it at the end of this question so you don't need to click the link. I already asked a different question about it [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2256355/why-this-finite-difference-method-is-stable-for-r-leq1-2). However that was about stability, and this is not, so I am asking a new question rather than editing.

**Question:** I need to compare my answer with the *theoretical order of accuracy* of this method, which is not mentioned in this Wikipedia page, and I don't know what it is at all. What is it, how do I calculate it?

**Edit:** Is it the $O(k)$ and $O(h^2)$ terms after the approximations for the derivatives? If so the problem still remains that I don't know how to calculate these of compare them with anything.

**Edit 2:** From the comments, I know what $O$ notation is. But how can it be manipulated in the step from equation $(2)$ to $(3)$? I don't understand how addition or subtraction of these two factors could work, and don't see how we can move things around to achieve division.

PS: I don't know quite what the (order) tag means, if it is appropriate then please edit it in. Thanks in advance for any help :)

---

*Summary of Wikipedia page:*

> We have the differential equation $$U_t=U_{xx}\tag1$$
>   We want to numerically approximate the points at $(x_j,t_n)$ by $u_j^n$. By expressing the derivatives as $$U_t\approx\frac{u_j^{n+1}-u_j^n}{k}+O(k)\text{ and }U_{xx}\approx\frac{u_{j+1}^n-2u_j^n+u_{j-1}^n}{h^2}+O(h^2),\tag2$$ we can rearrange to get
>   $$u_j^{n+1}=(1-2r)u_j^n+r u_{j-1}^n+r u_{j+1}^n\tag3$$ where $r=k/h^2$

Comment: This may answer your question: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation

Comment: @JustinBenfield Thanks, I have now read this page. What I am still unsure of is how to manipulate these "added factors", since what would it mean to say $$O(k)-O(h^2)\text{ as }k,h\to\infty$$ When rearranging equation $(2)$ to equation $(3)$, what do we do with these factors? Surely rather than addition, it makes more sense to only do division and multiplication with these?